# Openlayers 3 + Ionic: How to add a layer from a geojson array of features?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, openlayers-3

I'm working on a mobile app using ionic framework and the openlayers 3 library and I want to show a map with different layers.

So far I could achieve this through the most common ways:

- Loading the layer from a .geojson file

  ```
      $rootScope.layers.push(new ol.layer.Vector({
  name:"Op. 201623061345",
  visible:true,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'layers/manzanas.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
      // Default data projection, if cannot be derived from data itself
      defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
  })
  }));
  ```
- From OSM servers:

  ```
  $rootScope.layers.push( new ol.layer.Tile({
   name:"Mapa base",
   visible:true,
   source: new ol.source.OSM(),
   projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326')}));
  ```

  But I cannot use those methods because:
- I don't have the .geojson file in the app directory (I donwload it with cordova file/filetransfer plugins into the phone storage, therefore I can't access it from the controller script).
- It must be offline (the app will be used in some places where internet is not available).

So, the only factible way I've found is the following: Firstly I get the .geojson file through cordova.file plugin and save it into a local variable,and then use it in the layer. But I have tried a LOT of things (by now I've been researching for about 1 week) and none of them worked:

```
 var geojson_format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
 var vectors = new ol.layer.Vector(nom);
 var features = geojson_format.readFeatures($rootScope.capas);

 if(features.constructor != Array) {
   features = [features];
 }
 vectors.reportError = true;
 vectors.addFeatures(features);
 $rootScope.layers.push(vectors);
```

[from an answer in gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31550/how-to-get-geojson-features-using-openlayers),

```
     var geojson_format = new ol.format.GeoJSON(); 
 var features = geojson_format.readFeatures($rootScope.capas);
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [features]
 });
 var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
 });
 $rootScope.layers.push(vectorLayer);
```

[from another one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124179/ol3-openlayers-3-add-geolocation-marker).
The .geojson file is a feature collection like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS:84" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 159706, "name": "0003", "key": "01 G3               0534   0003", "ord10703": "U\/C2", "delegacion": "casco", "cod_deleg": "2", "country": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -57.964630850040791, -34.909304015452506 ], [ -57.964413402562315, -34.909105648618414 ], [ -57.964321847662283, -34.909159056511633 ], [ -57.964546924832433, -34.909361238059503 ], [ -57.964630850040791, -34.909304015452506 ] ] ] ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 159707, "name": "0001  B", "key": "01 G3               0534   0001  B", "ord10703": "U\/C2", "delegacion": "casco", "cod_deleg": "2", "country": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -57.96471477514141, -34.909239163271771 ], [ -57.96479870029593, -34.909178125877908 ], [ -57.96472240294829, -34.909109460445165 ], [ -57.964638477847657, -34.909174312625929 ], [ -57.96471477514141, -34.909239163271771 ] ] ] ] } },....
```

Whatever I try, I can't get the data displayed and I keep getting different errors (TypeError: d.Wa is not a function; could not read property ... of null, etc).
Please note that loading the same .geojson file with the first method that I quoted works perfectly.
Sorry for the long post, I hope it's clear.
Thanks!